# How can I "link" different files to my folder without using soft link?

Tags: macos, finder

I have some some folders look like this structure:

- **Buy** folder -> state_diagram_for_buy, activity_diagram_for_buy
- **Sell** folder -> state_diagram_for_sell, activity_diagram_for_sell
- **Search** folder -> state_diagram_for_search, activity_diagram_for_search

I want to group all the state_diagrams and activity diagrams in two folder.
So one folder is used to store state_diagram and another one is used to store the activity diagrams.

However, I don't want to copy those file, since any changes in the original files cannot reflect on the copy one. I know there is a Unix command: `ln` can be used to create the linking. But are there other ways to create the linkings in finder because I don't know to type the commands many time...

Comment: Might it not be easier to use one folder with the standard names you have then to find all but - esearch for *_buy.* and for start diagram for state* . ln is the shortest you can type so I don't see how it could be quicker

Answer (score 2):

You can create a smart search for each type of file. Make a search in Finder by file name (you can also enter other criteria) and when you're satisfied with the results, save it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an *alias* for a file using the File > Make Alias menu in Finder.  (Alternatively, drag the file icon whilst holding <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>.)

So, for example, set up your *Buy*, *Sell* and *Search* folders as you describe.  Then create a *State diagrams* folder, and <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-drag the state_diagram files into it.

Answer (score -3):

hipSpace.app is a temporal workspace. It records our informations using **references** on them, it lets dedicated applications to manage the location of their own stuff. By defaults, adding, drag&dropping or copy&pasting into hipSpace, will not move neither change our original informations.
Hope it can help you.
http://hipSpace.net

Comment: This sounds more like a generic product description than an actual answer to a quite specific question. How would the OP use hipSpace to solve the problem described in the question?

Comment: hipSpace is like a Folder of soft links (alias). Code4j can drag (or copy/paste) all activiy_diagram (_buy, _sell, _search) into it ! Ok, for the moment hipSpace represents one Folder of aliases, Code4j needs 2 Folders. A workaround could to divide the Space in 2 parts.